# Getting Order_ID in Custom Module for Magento 2 Admin

Tags: php, magento, magento2

Could someone help me to write orderID parameter in my custom module's onclick-setLocation? I am trying to add **a button with custom URL** to *admin>sales>order->view* page.

Please check the code at below. I just want to write my button's onclick function as like **external_link.php?id=8**.

```
<?php

namespace Myself\AdminInvoiceColumn\Plugin\Block\Widget\Button;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button\Toolbar as ToolbarContext;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button\ButtonList;

class Toolbar
{
/**
 * @param ToolbarContext $toolbar
 * @param AbstractBlock $context
 * @param ButtonList $buttonList
 * @return array
 */



public function beforePushButtons(
    ToolbarContext $toolbar,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock $context,
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button\ButtonList $buttonList
) { 
    if (!$context instanceof \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View) {
        return [$context, $buttonList];
    } 
    $buttonList->update('order_edit', 'class', 'edit');
    $buttonList->update('order_invoice', 'class', 'invoice primary');
    $buttonList->update('order_invoice', 'sort_order', (count($buttonList->getItems()) + 1) * 10);

    $buttonList->add('order_review',
        [
            'label' => __('Custom Button'),
            'onclick' => 'setLocation(\'/external_link.php?'.$id.'\')',
            'class' => 'review'
        ]
    );


    return [$context, $buttonList];
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, the easiest and best way to create a custom button along with adding order id to make a custom url is by creating `setLayout` plugin function.

First of all, you must declare plugin in `Custom_Vendor/Custom_Module/etc/adminhtml/di.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View">
        <plugin name="custom_button" type="Custom_Vendor\Custom_Module\Plugin\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

and, then extend `before` function something like this:

```
<?php
namespace Custom_Vendor\Custom_Module\Plugin\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order;

use Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View as OrderView;

class View
{
    public function beforeSetLayout(OrderView $subject)
    {
        $orderId = $subject->getOrderId();

        /**
         * Change url as per your need and you could also 
         * use $subject->getUrl('module/controller/action')
         */
        $url = '/external_link.php?' . $orderId;

        $subject->addButton(
            'order_custom_button',
            [
                'label' => __('Custom Button'),
                'class' => 'review',
                'onclick' => "setLocation('{$url}')"
            ]
        );
    }
}
```